# Error al cambiar la codificación de mi archivo HTML a utf-8

Tags: html, utf-8

Mi problema es el siguiente: debo imprimir un texto de un API y este me viene con caracteres especiales y así me los imprime, y pensaba que con el meta charset="utf-8", seria suficiente, pero no, despues investigue y he hecho estos cambios, tanto en mi editor de texto lo guarde como como [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puse esto en preferencias->herramientas->usuario 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al principio me salia esto en consola 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de tantos intentos logre que me diera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque leí que ascii y utf-8 eran del mismo grupo, bueno ya lo cambie, pero aun asi no me hace nada, me sigue mostrando los caracteres
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero alguien me pueda ayudar, muchas gracias !

Comment: Las entidades HTML (como por ejemplo el `&#039;`) no tienen absolutamente nada que ver con la codificación del texto... ¿Podrías mostrar tu HTML? ... Y, por cierto, te conviene usar utf8 **sin** BOM, para evitar problemas en el futuro. Cuando se conoce la codificación, no se debería usar BOM.

Comment: Prueba a mostrar dichos textos con echo html_entity_decode($texto); de php. Si lo tienes que hacer en javascript sería con unescape(texto);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método unescape en JavaScript está deprecado. Cuando tienes caracteres especiales de HTML y estás en el front-end, puedes sacar provecho del DOM creando un elemento temporal en memoria, asignándole la propiedad `.innerHTML` para que interprete los caracteres y devolviendo el texto de dicho elemento. Suena un poco confuso, pero me refiero a lo siguiente:

```
const escapeHTML = (textWithSpecialCharacters) => {
  const el = document.createElement('p'); // Crea elemento temporal
  el.innerHTML = textWithSpecialCharacters; // Convierte tus caracteres especiales a HTML
  return el.textContent; // Obtiene solo el texto del elemento eliminando caracteres especiales
};
```

Lo puedes probar llamando a la función:

```
escapeHTML('Rock n&#039; Roll jokes'); // "Rock n' Roll jokes"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @ivandevp, me funciono :)